# Processing 3 - how to set default opacity

Tags: colors, processing

This is driving me crazy. Here is my setup:

```java
background(0);
stroke(255,255,255,255);
```

When I put a pixel out, then query the same pixel, the colors does not match:

```java
point(2,2);
int x = get(2,2);
print(red(x));
print(green(x));
print(blue(x));
```

What I get is: 223 223 223
Why do I get 223 instead of 255?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because by default, Processing enables anti-aliasing. This adds blurriness and transparency to shapes, including points. Usually this is a good thing, as it makes your drawings look nicer.

But if you want to disable anti-aliasing because you need exact colors, then just call the `noSmooth()` function before you do your drawing:

```
noSmooth();
background(0);
stroke(255,255,255,255);
point(2,2);
int x = get(2,2);
print(red(x));
print(green(x));
print(blue(x));
```

This prints out `255` like you're expecting. More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/noSmooth_.html).

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted.